# Write a Pandas Series out of certain csv file columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, time-series, timestamp

Let's say I am trying to make a (Pandas) Series from 2 csv files that look like this:

```
A.csv (no column names)

    28/05/2020 22:15,0.88
    28/05/2020 22:30,0.85
    28/05/2020 22:45,0.97


B.csv 

    28/05/2020 22:15,0.05
    28/05/2020 22:30,0.12
    28/05/2020 22:45,0.18
```

The array would have to look something like this:

```
[0.88,0.85,0.97,..., 0.05,0.12,0.18,..., timestamp(28/05/2020 22:15)]
```

So far i have come up with this to write the array:

```
datarow= pd.DataFrame
for k, v in datarow():


    if k < 96:
           data = pd.concat([A, pd.Series([v], index=[k])])
           data.append(pd.Series(v,0), ignore_index=True)
              
    elif k < 2*96:
           data = pd.concat([B, pd.Series([v], index=[96-k])])
           data.append(pd.Series(v,0), ignore_index=True)
            
    else:
           timestamp = v
```

When printed, it shows an empty array. What are possible solutions?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want the Series to look like? Include first 2 and last 2 fields.

Comment: Something like this [0.88,0.85,.....,1590700280,0] with the large number being the converted timestamp from 28/05/2020 and the time

Comment: Why is the last element `0` ?

Comment: I am sorry, i mixed the timestamp and the number. The number represents the initial charge but you could put it at 100 also for example.

Comment: Your question is very unclear regarding what exactly you want. You also didn't mention what have you *tried* so far. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a reference to how to properly ask a question.

Comment: I will edit the question to better fit the standards, thank you for your help so far

Comment: On which line is the key error raised?

Comment: Charge0= dff.loc[96]

Answer (score 0):

First create a `Series` out of the desired column as follows:

```
series = dataframe.column
```

Extract the value of the first timestamp of the `timestamps` column:

```
timestamp = dataframe.timestamps.iloc[0]
```

Set the last field of your `series` to be the timestamp you just extracted:

```
series.iloc[-1] = timestamp
```

Convert your series to a list:

```
series_as_list = series.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, could you tell me what the reason is to use a list at the end?

Comment: Because you asked for an array and since Python doesn't have such data structure (unless you use numpy i guess) you can use a list. Let me know if my answer solved what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried to name the columns of the csv file in order to use dataframe.column, but this seems to mess up the previous code. Is there another way to acces a column (without name) after reading the file like this: `pv_Module = pd.read_csv('example.csv', index_col=0, header=None, parse_dates=True,
                        squeeze=True)`

Comment: My actual problem includes creating this series which will include the columns of 3 different csv files, but I will be very thankful if it works for one. I am using numpy if that is easier. Apologies if I don't manage to ask the right questions.